Small space appearing before string in remix
Hello I saw that type casting from bytes to string gave the same result whether the bytes are a string encoded or encodePacked. So I am trying some small contract in remix, to see how that works and there was a small difference.
I wrote this small contract.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Test {
    function testStrings() public pure returns(bytes memory, bytes memory, string memory, string memory, bool){
        // how strings are encoded in memory
        bytes memory data1 = abi.encode(32, 5, bytes32(abi.encodePacked("hello")));
        bytes memory data2 = abi.encodePacked("hello");
        return (
            data1,
            data2,
            string(data1),
            string(data2),
            // testing for string equality
            keccak256(bytes(string(data1))) == keccak256(bytes(string(data2)))
        );
    }
}

The strings are almost equal after type casting, but not equal as the hash equality suggests. Can someone explain why there is this difference ? Is that introduced on type casting ? There is a small space before the string that comes from the full encoding as you can see on the image...


In the context of encoding bytes and strings in Solidity, "extra space" typically refers to padding added to make data fit a certain size, often 32 bytes. This is common when working with bytes32 types or when using abi.encode.
If you want to get the exact same bytes data, then you need to replace the abi.encodePacked with abi.encode, in case of data2, like:
bytes memory data2 = abi.encode("hello");

As, abi.encode("hello") means encoding the data without any padding. So when you're doing abi.encode(32, 5, bytes32(abi.encodePacked("hello"))), it's explicitly introducing the same padding to the resultant encodePacked bytes, as it will include the following:

The encoded value 32 as a 32-byte integer.

The encoded value 5 as a 32-byte integer.

The bytes32 value, which is the packed "hello" string padded to 32 bytes.


This results in a complex byte sequence:

0x20 (32 in decimal) as a 32-byte integer: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020

0x05 (5 in decimal) as a 32-byte integer: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

The packed "hello" string, padded to 32 bytes: 0x68656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.


The revised code to get the exact same bytes data would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Test {
    function testStrings() public pure returns(bytes memory, bytes memory, string memory, string memory, bool){
        // how strings are encoded in memory
        bytes memory data1 = abi.encode(32, 5, bytes32(abi.encodePacked("hello")));
        bytes memory data2 = abi.encode("hello");
        return (
            data1,
            data2,
            string(data1),
            string(data2),
            // testing for string equality
            keccak256(bytes(string(data1))) == keccak256(bytes(string(data2)))
        );
    }
}

